# Cordova wait until user gave premission to use location services

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, location

I have to check if the user disabled the location services i do this like so:

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled(function(enabled) {
            if (enabled === false) {
              $state.go("errorTwo");
            }
        }, function(error) {
            alert("The following error occurred: " + error);
        });
      }
```

But the problem is, that if the user starts the app the first time, the error already runs. The function should wait until the user gave premission to use the location services. How can I do this? 
Any help much appreciated!

Comment: did you solved this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation states](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#islocationenabled) for `isLocationEnabled()`:

> Returns true if the device setting for location is on. On Android this returns true if Location Mode is switched on. On iOS this returns true if Location Services is switched on.

i.e. this only checks if the device setting is enabled.

However, you can either use [`isLocationAvailable()`](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#islocationavailable)

> On iOS and Windows 10 Mobile this returns true if both the device setting is enabled AND the application is authorized to use location. When location is enabled, the locations returned are by a mixture GPS hardware, network triangulation and Wifi network IDs.
>   On Android, this returns true if Location mode is enabled and any mode is selected (e.g. Battery saving, Device only, High accuracy) AND if the app is authorised to use location. When location is enabled, the locations returned are dependent on the location mode

This checks "if both the device setting is enabled AND the application is authorized to use location":

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationAvailable(
   function(enabled) {
       if (enabled === false) {
           $state.go("errorTwo");
       }, 
   }, function(error) {
       alert("The following error occurred: " + error);
   }
});
```

Or, you can call [`isLocationAuthorized()`](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#islocationauthorized) to check if the app is authorized to use location, before checking the device setting:

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationAuthorized(function(authorized){
    console.log("Location is " + (authorized ? "authorized" : "unauthorized"));
    if(authorized){
       cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled(
           function(enabled) {
               if (enabled === false) {
                   $state.go("errorTwo");
               }, 
           }, function(error) {
               alert("The following error occurred: " + error);
           }
        });
    }
}, function(error){
    console.error("The following error occurred: "+error);
});
```

To "wait" until the app has permission to use location before checking, you must take control of the request for location authorization:

```
function checkLocationSetting(){
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled(
        function(enabled) {
            if (enabled === false) {
                $state.go("errorTwo");
            }, 
        }, function(error) {
            alert("The following error occurred: " + error);
        }
    });
}

cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationAuthorized(function(authorized){
    console.log("Location is " + (authorized ? "authorized" : "unauthorized"));
    if(authorized){
        checkLocationSetting();
    }else{
        cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestLocationAuthorization(function(status){
            if(status == cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED){
                checkLocationSetting();
            }else{
                console.warn("Permission denied to use location");
            }
        }, function(error){
            console.error(error);
        });        
    }
}, function(error){
    console.error("The following error occurred: "+error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must determine if this is th initial run of your application. To do this you can add this code and adjust to your needs.

//service

```
 .factory('Application', function ($window) {
    return {
      setInitialRun = function (initial) {
          $window.localStorage["initialRun"] = (initial ? "true" : "false");
      },
      isInitialRun = function () {
         var value = $window.localStorage["initialRun"] || "true";
         return value == "true";
      }
    };
});
```

in your app.js

```
.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $state, Application) {
     var state = "mainPage";  // whatever, the main page of your app

     if (Application.isInitialRun()) {
           Application.setInitialRun(false);
           state = "intro";
     }

     $state.go(state);
});
```